# Find the maximum value of $xyzw$ if $x+2y+4z+8w=16$

Tags: inequality

Find the maximum value of $xyzw$ if $x+2y+4z+8w=16$.

---

I can solve this question by using Lagrange's multiplier method and find that the maximum value of $xyzw$ is $4$.
Also i can find the maximum value of $xyzw$ using the theorem that if sum of the numbers is constant,then the product of the numbers is maximum when they all are equal.So $x.2y.4z.8w$ is maximum when $x=2y=4z=8w=4$ and maximum $xyzw=\frac{4\times4\times4\times4}{2\times4\times8}=4$

---

But i want to find the maximum value using $AM-GM$ inequality which i am not able to do.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Find the maximum value of $x\cdot 2y\cdot 4z\cdot 8w$ under these conditions, and that will give you the maximum value of $xyzw$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use AM-GM $$x+2y+4z+8w\ge 4\sqrt[4]{x\cdot 2y\cdot 4z\cdot 8w}$$

Answer (score 3):

For $x,y,z,w>0,$

$$\dfrac{x+2y+4z+8w}4\ge\sqrt[4]{x\cdot2y\cdot 4z\cdot8w}$$

$$\implies64xyzw\le\left(\dfrac{x+2y+4z+8w}4\right)^4$$ the equality occurs iff all the summands are equal